# three.js add css to loaded texture

Tags: javascript, css, svg, three.js

Using `three.js` I am currently loading an image `img.svg` onto a mesh/planet/sphere as such:

```
function createPlanet(){
  var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("img.svg");
    texture.repeat.set( 4, 2 );
    texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    moonMat =  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial ({
        color: 0x4c00b4,
        wireframe: false,
        shading:THREE.FlatShading,
        map:texture
    });

    var moonGeometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(530, 1 );
    moon = new THREE.Mesh(moonGeometry, moonMat);

    scene.add( moon );
}
```

How can I add CSS to apply only the image that's mapped onto the mesh?